# CORS Issue - Angular 8 - NodeJS & ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, cors

I've tried a few different solutions from other threads and suspect I'm missing something small here.

I have an AngularJS 8 application, running on Node 10 with ExpressJS. Having some CORS issues when trying to access Google's People API.

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections' from origin 'http://app.x.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

My frontend code looks like:

```
    return this.httpClient.get(this.API_URL, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        Authorization: `Bearer ${authtoken}`,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:4200',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
      })
    });
  }
```

My server side code:

```
let express = require('express'),
  path = require('path'),
  cors = require('cors');
// Connecting mongoDB
var compression = require('compression')
var session = require("express-session");

let app = express();
app.use(session({
  secret: '#######################',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}));
app.use(compression())
app.use(cors());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});


/*var corsOptions = {
  origin: '*',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
*/

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/###')));
app.use('/*', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/##')));
// Create port
const port = 8080;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Connected to port ' + port)
})

// Find 404 and hand over to error handler
app.use((req, res, next) => {

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8888');

  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
  // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  next();
});


app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.message);
  if (!err.statusCode) err.statusCode = 500;
  {
    res.status(err.statusCode).send(err.message);
  }


  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');

  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
  // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  if (!err.statusCode) err.statusCode = 500;
  {
    res.status(err.statusCode).send(err.message);
  }


  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8888');

  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
  // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  next();
});
```

As you can see, I've tried a couple of different approaches. Would appreciate any suggestions.

Thank You

Comment: its nothing on your client or server side can do directly hitting developers.google.com/ from your client. your backend should make this request.

Comment: You'll need to make the call to the Google API from the server, not the client. the access headers in your http call are only allowed to be set on the controlling server and are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue in another way. Using the Gapi library (javascript: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/reference.md ) and its Auth, I was able to login, get the JWT and use that as a credential.

```
    const googleUser = await googleAuth.signIn();

    const token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;

    const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(token);
    await firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential);

    return googleUser;
```

Using that credential login to firebase. All the while, being loggedin to Google Api's thanks to Gapi's Javascript Library. You can use a gapi instance then to request resources and api's depending on your scope of course.

```
 const contacts = await gapi.client.request({
        'path': 'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?personFields=email_addresses,names&pageToken=CAAQwo2YuIUuGgYKAghkEAI&pageSize=2000',

      })
```

No CORS issues, no fuss. Just posting incase it helps someone else save some time.